# How to access values in kivy python classes from different screens?

Tags: python, kivy

I have the following basic python file that consumes a number and returns the number * 10.

```
class SomeOperation:
    
    def __init__(self, input_num=100):
        self.input_num = input_num
    
    def do_something(self):
        print(self.input_num * 10)
        return self.input_num * 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = SomeOperation()
    q.do_something()
```

I would like to call this script in the `PlaySetUp` screen of the below app.
Here a slider will determine `input_num` and also have a play button that will take me to the `PlayScreen` of the app.

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from someoperation import SomeOperation

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WindowManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class MainWindow(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class PlaySetUp(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlaySetUp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
class PlayScreen(Screen, SomeOperation):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlayScreen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class NumberSelection(BoxLayout):
     
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NumberSelection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.input_num = 10
        
        self.input_num_value = Label(text='10')
        self.add_widget(self.input_num_value)
        
        self.number_slider = Slider(min=10, max=100, step=10)
        self.number_slider.bind(value = self.on_value)        
        self.add_widget(self.number_slider)

    def on_value(self, widget, value):
        self.input_num = value
        self.input_num_value.text = str(value)

kv = Builder.load_file('sample.kv')

class SomeApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SomeApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    
    def build(self):
        return kv
```

The kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    PlaySetUp:
    PlayScreen:
        id: play_screen

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "Play"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "play_set_up"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

<PlaySetUp>:
    name: "play_set_up"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        NumberSelection:
        Button:
            text: "Go!"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "play_screen"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        Button:
            text: "Back!"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"        
        
                
<PlayScreen>:
    name: "play_screen"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: #TODO: show the output of SomeOperation
        Button:
            text: "Run"
            on_release: #TODO: re-run SomeOperation with same set up as in the PlaySetUp screen
        Button:
            text: "Back!"
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = "play_set_up"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

I would like to run the `SomeOperation` script automatically in the `PlayScreen`
plus re-run it every time I press the `Run` button. The result should always be the same unless I press the `back` button and change the slider value in the `PlaySetUp` screen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say you want to run it in the `PlayScreen`, but in response to what?  There has to be some event that triggers a callback into your class.  Once you have that, then it's just Python coding, like in your sample.

Comment: In response the `Go!` button in `PlaySetUp`. Here the user interracts with the slider then presses the `Go!` button to go to the `PlayScreen` where `SomeOperation` is executed based on the slider parameter of the `PlaySetUp`

Comment: Then your `on_release:` events need to have `root.pressed()`, and you need to add `pressed` methods to your button classes.

Comment: ok so that sorts out the "automatically run `SomeOperation`" part. But what about the "plus re-run it every time I press the `Run` button" in the `PlayScreen` with the same parameter as the slider from the the previous screen?

Comment: Same thing.  Your `on_release:` for the "Run"` button needs to call a function in the `PlayScreen` class, like `root.pressed()`.  You decide in that function how to handle it.

Comment: So how do you call the Slider value from the `PlaySetUp`? with `x = NumberSelection() input_num = x.input_num`?

Comment: I don't know how the components of a dialog are accessed from the Python code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247565/discussion-between-realragedontquit-and-tim-roberts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that you can set variable names in the build function of the App.

```
class SomeApp(App):
    my_int = NumericProperty(0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SomeApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def build(self):
        return kv
```

then the function for the slider can set the value with:

```
def on_value(self, widget, value):
    self.input_num = value
    self.input_num_value.text = str(value)
    SomeApp.my_int = value
```

This way all other functions can subsequently call this new value